# C Doubly Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

It works, but it seems a bit long winded. I'd like some critiquing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node * previous;
  struct node * next;
};

struct linked_list
{
  struct node * first;
  struct node * last;
};

struct linked_list * init_list(struct node * node)
{
  struct linked_list * ret = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
  ret->first = node;
  ret->last = node;
  return ret;
}

struct node * create_node(int data)
{
  struct node * ret = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  ret->data = data;
  ret->previous = NULL;
  ret->next = NULL;
  return ret;
}

void destroy_list(struct linked_list * list)
{
  struct node * node = list->first, *next = NULL;
  while(node != NULL)
  {
    next = node->next;
    free(node);
    node = next;
  }
  free(list);
}

void push_front(struct linked_list * list, struct node * node)
{
  if(list->first != NULL)
  {
    node->next = list->first;
    list->first->previous = node;
  }
  else list->last = node;
  list->first = node;
}

void push_back(struct linked_list * list, struct node * node)
{
  if(list->last != NULL)
  {
    node->previous = list->last;
    list->last->next = node;
    list->last = node;
  }
  else push_front(list, node);
}

void insert_after(struct node * node, struct node * to_add)
{
  to_add->previous = node;
  to_add->next = node->next;
  node->next = to_add;
}

void remove_node(struct node * node)
{
  node->previous->next = node->next;
  node->next->previous = node->previous;
  free(node);
}
```

Comment: This is actually pretty clean and concise. You can probably get away with something more concise which somehow merges the two structs into one, but most likely at the expense of readability, which I wouldn't recommend doing.

Comment: This `if(...) { ...; ...; } else ...;` where the `else` is not a block isn't a particularly clear style to read. If the `if` has a block, the `else` should have a block too. The one in `push_front` is especially sneaky because the `else` has a statement immediately following it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments this code is not long winded at all.  It is very clean in general.  Too clean in fact as you will see below.

- You cannot create an empty linked list with your `init_list`.  However, in other parts of your code you assume `list` may be empty.  It is useful to be able to create an empty linked list since you may not know what you want your first node to be in advance.  I'd suggest changing `init_list`.
- I personally like symmetry in linked list code.  You can always create the dual of one function by swapping all prevs with nexts and all heads with tails.  I don't think your `push_back` code should call `push_front`.  You can handle the `else` condition just like you did in `push_front` except by swapping variable names.
- `insert_after` is incomplete.  Remember this is a doubly linked list.  Also the function doesn't handle the case when you insert after the current `list->last`.  You need to add the linked list to the function arguments.
- `remove_node` does not handle all cases.  What if `node` was the head of the list?  What if it was the tail of the list?  What if it was both the head and the tail?  You don't actually have to write three different cases to handle this but you can.
- As simply a style choice I would rename `previous` to `prev`
- I am ignoring that you never check for your pointers being `NULL`

**Edit:**

This code actually can produce an empty list by passing `NULL` in as an argument to `init_list`

Comment: I agree with all of your cases except the empty list. Couldn't you pass NULL as the node and it would technically be empty?

Comment: Indeed you can.  I will edit the answer.

Comment: I also agree with your critique, except for the style point. C prgrmrs hv a blf tht rmving ltrs frm wrds is smhow bttr bt it rly is nt. Keystrokes are cheap; don't be shy about using them. `previous` is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 4):

You've done a good job of breaking your list manipulating into small, logic functions typical of a doubly linked list. I do think you need to take it a step farther though: the manipulation (allocation, setting, etc) of `node` is an implementation detail. What you're really wanting to operate on are `int`s, and `node` should just be used to traverse the list (if you wanted to go all out you could even encapsulate the traversal so `node` is completely hidden, but meh... I think that's taking it a bit too far since doubly linked lists are so simple).

---

You seem to have forgotten insert_before. I would expect it to be there since insert_after is there and this is a doubly linked list.

---

Though it's not worth worrying about it unless you're working on non-trivial C programs or developing a library others will use, you should be mindful of potential name collisions and use a prefix.

For example, if you remove the requirement that the list be initialized with an element, you'll end up with `init_list(void)` as a signature which is fairly likely to exist in some other library. This is the reason that libraries all use some kind of prefix (`curl_`, `apr_`, `ev_`, etc).

Though it's not important as long as you're aware of the possibility and willing to run that risk, it becomes incredibly important in anything that's a non-trivial program or even a trivial program with dependencies. In addition, if you are to ever publish code for someone else to use, you can't predict what kind of collisions they might have. In short, if this code were to be 'real' code, it would need to have some kind of (ideally unique) prefix on method/type names.

---

```
enum linked_list_result { LINKED_LIST_SUCCESS = 0, LINKED_LIST_ERR_MEM = 1 };

struct linked_list * init_list(void);

void destroy_list(struct linked_list * list);

/* Your functions now return a result type instead of void since the malloc could fail */
enum linked_list_result push_front(struct linked_list * list, int value);

enum linked_list_result push_back(struct linked_list * list, int value);

enum linked_list_result insert_before(struct node * node, int value);

enum linked_list_result insert_after(struct node * node, int value);

void remove_node(struct node * node);

/* This becomes hidden in the implementation file */
static struct node * create_node(int data);
```

Comment: This is actually pretty informative. I appreciate the name collision advice.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the bugs that twohundredping already pointed out, I want to further point out that the `insert_after` and `remove_node` functions are flawed in concept because they don't pass the list to the function. Therefore, you can wind up with a list that has incorrect first and last pointers if you use those functions.

I think both those functions should take a `list` argument and should update `list->first` and `list->last` as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to always either check the return value of any `malloc` and return `NULL` as to not crash. Or at least do an `assert(ret != NULL);`.

Also `assert` for what should be considered errors by incorrectly using the API. For example passing a `NULL` node to the `remove_node` or `insert_after` functions.